# JavaScript - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

мне нужно сделать так что бы по нажатию на один из них половина содержания становилась не видимым а другая видимым. 
Т.е у меня есть блок

```
<ul>
<li>
<div class="answer" id='.$answervalue['id'].'>
    <p id="number" style="padding-top:7px;color:white;font-size:14pt; font-wegiht:bold;font-family: Arial;">Ответить</p>
    <p id="answer_quest" style="visibility:hidden;padding-top:7px;color:white;font-size:14pt; font-wegiht:bold;font-family: Arial;">'.$answervalue['answer'].'</p>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Я хочу что бы по нажатию на него у меня скрывалось слово ответить и появлялся сам ответ. Как это можно сделать?

p.s там где $answevalue['id'] уникальный номер блока c ответом.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.answer ').click(function() {
        $('#number').css({
            display: 'none',
        });
        $('#answer_quest').css({
            visibility: 'visible ',
        });
    });

    });
</script>
```

Написал такой кусок кода но он выполняется для всех :(

решил использовать списки в которые заключил сам блок :)
теперь вопрос как узнать на какой из элементов списка нажали.

Comment: Не надо создавать новый вопрос, если вы хотите изменить уже заданный. Для этого внизу вопроса есть ссылка **править**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как понимаю, то на странице у вас может быть множество таких блоков. Нельзя на одной странице присваивать один и тот же id элементам, id - уникальный идентификатор объекта.
Что касается самого скрипта (заменил id на классы):

```
$('.answer').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.number').hide();
    $(this).children('.answer_quest').show();
    return false;
});
```